# setAutoCreateRowSorter doesn't sort table column correctly after update

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable, integer

While developing a small task manager, I have noticed that columns aren't sorted correctly. To discard problems with my program, I have created a minimal version but it still fails to order the unique column right.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TableSortTest extends JFrame
{
    private final JTable table;
    private final ATableModel model;

    public TableSortTest ()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation (EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize (1366, 768);
        setLocationRelativeTo (null);

        model = new ATableModel ();
        table = new JTable ();
        table.setFillsViewportHeight (true);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter (true);
        table.setModel (model);

        add (new JScrollPane (table), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setVisible (true);

        Worker worker = new Worker ();
        worker.execute ();
    }

    private class Pair
    {
        int index;
        int value;
    }

    private class Worker extends SwingWorker <Void, Pair>
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground ()
        {
            while (!isCancelled ())
            {
                Random r = new Random ();
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    int indice = getIndexInRange (0, 99);
                    Pair p = new Pair ();
                    p.index = indice;
                    p.value = Math.abs (r.nextInt ());
                    publish (p);
                }

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep (1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    ie.printStackTrace ();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void process (List <Pair> items)
        {
            for (Pair p : items)
            {
                model.setValueAt (p.value, p.index, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int getIndexInRange (int min, int max)
    {
        return (min + (int) (Math.random () * ((max - min) + 1)));
    }

    private class ATableModel extends AbstractTableModel
    {
        private final Integer [] data;

        public ATableModel ()
        {
            data = new Integer [100];

            Random r = new Random ();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                data [i] = Math.abs (r.nextInt ());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount ()
        {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount ()
        {
            return data.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt (int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            return data [rowIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt (Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
        {
            data [rowIndex] = (Integer) value;
            fireTableRowUpdated (rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass (int columnIndex)
        {
            return Integer.class;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName (int col)
        {
            return "Column";
        }
    }

    public static final void main (String [] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (() ->
        {
            try
            {
                new TableSortTest ();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace ();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have tried with a `ScheduledExecutorService` + `Runnable` and a `Timer` + `TimerTask` just to test if it was a threading problem, but the behavior is the same. I have also read the Java Tutorial page about the subject. Given that my table only uses standard types I think that a simple `table.setAutoCreateRowSorter (true);` should do the job, shouldn't it?

Shouldn't the table be sorted after every modification/addition/removal even is fired?

Answer (score 2):

Using [`setSortsOnUpdates()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html#setSortsOnUpdates-boolean-), suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36533731/230513) by [@trcs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4464597/trcs), is the best general solution, but you may be able to optimize updates by the choice of `TableModelEvent` available to subclasses of [`AbstractTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html).

The critical issue is the implementation of `setValueAt()`. If you meant `fireTableRowsUpdated()`, instead of `fireTableRowUpdated()`, note that the parameters represent a range of rows, *not* a row & column. In this case, because "all cell values in the table's rows may have changed," the revised example below invokes `fireTableDataChanged()`. I've also changed the model to manage a `List<Integer>` and normalized the size, `N`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36522182/230513 */
public class TableSortTest extends JFrame {

    private final JTable table;
    private final ATableModel model;

    public TableSortTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        model = new ATableModel();
        table = new JTable(model){
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 500);
            }
        };
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.execute();
    }

    private class Pair {

        int index;
        int value;
    }

    private class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Pair> {

        private static final int N = 100;
        private final Random r = new Random();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() {
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    int index = r.nextInt(N);
                    Pair p = new Pair();
                    p.index = index;
                    p.value = Math.abs(r.nextInt());
                    publish(p);
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void process(List<Pair> items) {
            for (Pair p : items) {
                model.setValueAt(p.value, p.index, 0);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ATableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final int N = 100;
        private final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>(N);

        public ATableModel() {
            final Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                data.add(Math.abs(r.nextInt()));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return data.get(rowIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            data.set(rowIndex, (Integer) value);
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return Integer.class;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return "Column";
        }
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new TableSortTest();
        });
    }
}
```

Recognizing that this is just an example, the variation below optimizes updates by publishing a `List<Integer>`, which is passed *en bloc* to the `TableModel` via `process()`.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

/**
 * @ see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36522182/230513
 */
public class TableSortTest extends JFrame {

    private final JTable table;
    private final ATableModel model;

    public TableSortTest() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        model = new ATableModel();
        table = new JTable(model) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
                return new Dimension(200, 500);
            }
        };
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.execute();
    }

    private class Worker extends SwingWorker<List<Integer>, List<Integer>> {

        private static final int N = 100;
        private final Random r = new Random();
        private final List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>(N);

        @Override
        protected List<Integer> doInBackground() throws Exception {
            while (!isCancelled()) {
                data.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                    data.add(Math.abs(r.nextInt()));
                }
                publish(data);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    ie.printStackTrace(System.err);
                }
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<List<Integer>> chunks) {
            for (List<Integer> chunk : chunks) {
                model.update(chunk);
            }
        }
    }

    private class ATableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();

        public void update(List<Integer> data) {
            this.data = data;
            fireTableDataChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return data.get(rowIndex);
        }

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return Integer.class;
        }

        @Override
        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return "Column";
        }
    }

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new TableSortTest();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your quick answer **trashgod**. You're right, I meant `fireTableRowsUpdated ()` but I made a mistake when I wrote the code, sorry. The point is that `fireTableRowsUpdated (rowIndex, rowIndex)` and `fireTableCellUpdated (rowIndex, columnIndex)` both fail to sort the column correctly. In the real program most of the table rows do change from one iteration to the next so calling `fireTableDataChanged ()` makes perfect sense. But I didn't want to use it because if I select one or more rows to send a signal to the processes or whatever the selection is lost on every update. I have explored this way and found two forms of preserving the selection but it's a bit annoying and one of them breaks the selection with the keyboard. I show the necessary additions to the original code next.

The first form saves the selection before modifying the model and restores it after every update:

```
...
private class Worker extends SwingWorker <Void, Pair>
{
    private int [] selectedRows;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground ()
    {
        while (!isCancelled ())
        {
            // Save the selection before modifying the model
            int x = table.getSelectedRowCount ();
            if (x > 0)
            {
                selectedRows = new int [x];
                int [] tableSelection = table.getSelectedRows ();

                for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                {
                    selectedRows [i] = table.convertRowIndexToModel (tableSelection [i]);
                }
            }

            Random r = new Random ();
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getRowCount (); i++)
            {
                int indice = getIndexInRange (0, table.getRowCount () - 1);
                Pair p = new Pair ();
                p.index = indice;
                p.value = Math.abs (r.nextInt ());
                publish (p);
            }

            // If I put the code to restore the selection here, it doesn't work...
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep (1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
                ie.printStackTrace ();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void process (List <Pair> items)
    {
       for (Pair p : items)
       {
           model.setValueAt (p.value, p.index, 1);
       }

       // Restore the selection on every update
       if (selectedRows != null && selectedRows.length > 0)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++)
           {
               table.addRowSelectionInterval (table.convertRowIndexToView (selectedRows [i]), table.convertRowIndexToView (selectedRows [i]));
           }
       }
    }
}
...
```

The second form uses a `ListSelectionListener`, a `KeyListener`, and a flag. Selection with the keyboard doesn't work. To be honest, I don't know how did I come to get this solution. It probably was by chance:

```
public class TableSortTestSolucionConSelectionListener extends JFrame implements KeyListener
{
    ...
    private boolean ctrlOrShiftDown = false;
    private int [] selectedRows;

    @Override
    public void keyPressed (KeyEvent e)
    {
        ctrlOrShiftDown = e.isControlDown () || e.isShiftDown ();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased (KeyEvent e)
    {
       ctrlOrShiftDown = e.isControlDown () || e.isShiftDown ();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e)
    {
       ctrlOrShiftDown = e.isControlDown () || e.isShiftDown ();
    }

    public TableSortTestSolucionConSelectionListener ()
    {
        ...
        ListSelectionListener lsl = new ListSelectionListener ()
        {
            @Override
            public void valueChanged (ListSelectionEvent e)
            {
                if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting ())
                {
                    if (!ctrlOrShiftDown)
                    {
                        int x = table.getSelectedRowCount ();
                        if (x > 0)
                        {
                            selectedRows = new int [x];
                            int [] tableSelection = table.getSelectedRows ();

                            for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
                            {
                                selectedRows [i] = table.convertRowIndexToModel (tableSelection [i]);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Disable the listener to avoid infinite recursion
                    table.getSelectionModel ().removeListSelectionListener (this);

                    if (selectedRows != null && selectedRows.length > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRows.length; i++)
                        {
                            table.addRowSelectionInterval (table.convertRowIndexToView (selectedRows [i]), table.convertRowIndexToView (selectedRows [i]));
                        }
                    }

                    table.getSelectionModel ().addListSelectionListener (this);
                }
            }
        };

        table.getSelectionModel ().addListSelectionListener (lsl);
        ...      
     }
```

Fortunately today I have found a simple way to get the column sorted correctly and keep the current selection. You only have to add the following to your code:

```
TableRowSorter trs = (TableRowSorter) table.getRowSorter ();
trs.setSortsOnUpdates (true);
```

With this both `fireTableCellUpdated ()` and `fireTableRowsUpdated ()` work as I expected. To my understanding, `setAutoCreateRowSorter ()` is only used to sort the rows when you click on the table header.

Greetings.

Comment: `setSortsOnUpdates(true)` is probably optimal in this case; I'd avoid `KeyListener`.