# Updating off screen java components

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcomponent

I was profiling an existing application and noticed that the GUI thread was spending 20 percent of it's time updating a live data table that wasn't visible at the time.  As data comes in, the model is updated and a table change event is fired for the row that was updated.  Because the table has a sorter, JTable ultimately calls repaint for every change even though only a single row changed.

I'm looking for general information on how the JVM handles repaint calls and table change events for GUI Components not currently on screen.  From looking at the Netbeans profiler, it appears that Java is still painting components and updating tables even if they are currently not showing or clipped by other components.

- Is there a reason table changed events and repaint calls do not put
  off repainting until the component is actually visible and showing on
  the screen?
- Is there a reason why I should not override that
  behavior to only update/repaint if current showing on screen?
- Are there other strategies for handling live data in multiple screens, where only a subset of the components are visible at any given time?  Each component must display close to real-time so any strategy has to prevent a component from displaying stale data.

Comment: Painting to any area not visible on the screen (or outside the clip of the current Graphics) is already treated as a no-op.  And I doubt the JTable does a full repaint when one row changes;  I would expect it to call [convertRowIndexToView](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToView-int-) in order to repaint only the changed row.

Comment: This [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36520501/230513) compares `setSortsOnUpdates()` to optimizing table model events.