# Issues with JTable data from custom linked list

Tags: java, swing, linked-list, jtable

I'm having issues creating a table model to populate a JTable with Student objects from my custom linked list. Unfortunately, I have to create my own list instead of using the standard Java linked list.

Here's my primary class

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class StudentInterface {
public static void main(String[] args){
        new StudentInterface();
    }
    //create a linked list       
    MyList studentPack = new MyList();

public StudentInterface (){
    //create jFrame
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Student Information Interface");
    jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jFrame.setSize(400,300);
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
    jFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    jFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 400));

    //create content panes
    JPanel headerPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel combinedPanel = new JPanel();
    headerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    tablePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    combinedPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //add label to header content panel
    JLabel headerLabel1 = new JLabel("Welcome to the Student Information Interface");
    JLabel headerLabel2 = new JLabel("***Click a cell to edit data***");
    JLabel headerLabel3 = new JLabel("***Click a column header to sort***");
    headerLabel1.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    headerLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    headerLabel3.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    headerPanel.add(headerLabel1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    headerPanel.add(headerLabel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    headerPanel.add(headerLabel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //Where the GUI is created:
    JMenuBar menuBar;
    JMenu menu, submenu;
    JMenuItem exitMenuItem;
    JMenuItem saveMenuItem;
    JMenuItem loadMenuItem;

    //Create the menu bar.
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    //Build the main menu.
    menu = new JMenu("File");
    menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription("The only menu in this program that has menu items");
    menuBar.add(menu);

    //create menu items
    exitMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit",KeyEvent.VK_T);
    menu.add(exitMenuItem);
    jFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    //create table
    tableModel model;
    model = new tableModel(new MyList());
    JTable table = new JTable(model);

    //add list to list content panel
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(580, 400));
    tablePanel.add(scrollPane);

    //add buttons to button content panel
    JButton addButton = new JButton("Add");
    JButton removeButton = new JButton("Remove");
    buttonPanel.add(addButton);
    buttonPanel.add(removeButton);

    addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //verify pack is not full
        int packSize = studentPack.size();
        if (packSize >= 10)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "The interface is full. Please remove a student first.",
            "Interface Full",
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
            }

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
        JLabel labell = new JLabel("Please enter the first name of the student you would like to add:");
        p1.add(labell);
        p1.add(t1);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p1,"First Name",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String userFirstName = t1.getText();

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField t2 = new JTextField();
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Please enter the last name of the student you would like to add:");
        p2.add(label2);
        p2.add(t2);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p2,"Last Name",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String userLastName = t2.getText();

        JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField t3 = new JTextField();
        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Please enter the major of the student you would like to add:");
        p3.add(label3);
        p3.add(t3);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p3,"Major",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String userMajor = t3.getText();

        JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField t4 = new JTextField();
        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("Please enter the NetID of the student you would like to add:");
        p4.add(label4);
        p4.add(t4);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p4,"NetID",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String userNetID = t4.getText();

        JPanel p5 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField t5 = new JTextField();
        JLabel label5 = new JLabel("Please enter the gender of the student you would like to add:");
        p5.add(label5);
        p5.add(t5);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p5,"Gender",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String userGender = t5.getText();

        JPanel p6 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField t6 = new JTextField();
        JLabel label6 = new JLabel("Please enter the UIN of the student you would like to add:");
        p6.add(label6);
        p6.add(t6);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p6,"UIN",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String userUIN = t6.getText();

        JPanel p7 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField t7 = new JTextField();
        JLabel label7 = new JLabel("Please enter the age of the student you would like to add:");
        p7.add(label7);
        p7.add(t7);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p7,"Age",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String userAgeInput = t7.getText();
        int userAge = Integer.parseInt(userAgeInput);

        JPanel p8 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField t8 = new JTextField();
        JLabel label8 = new JLabel("Please enter the GPA of the student you would like to add:");
        p8.add(label8);
        p8.add(t8);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p8,"GPA",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String userGPAInput = t8.getText();
        double userGPA = Double.parseDouble(userGPAInput);

        //create student Student
        Student studentStudent = new Student(userFirstName, userLastName, userMajor, userGPA, userUIN, userNetID, userAge, userGender);

        //store Student in linked list
        model.addStudent(studentStudent);
        }
    });

    removeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //verify pack is not full
        if (studentPack.size() == 0)
            {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "The interface is empty. Please add a student first.",
            "Interface Empty",
            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            return;
            }

        JPanel p9 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField t9 = new JTextField();
        JLabel label9 = new JLabel("Please enter the first name of the student you would like to remove: **Case Sensitive**");
        p9.add(label9);
        p9.add(t9);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p9,"First Name",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String userFirstName = t9.getText();

        JPanel p10 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        JTextField t10 = new JTextField();
        JLabel label10 = new JLabel("Please enter the last name of the student you would like to remove: **Case Sensitive**");
        p10.add(label10);
        p10.add(t10);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,p10,"First Name",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        String userLastName = t10.getText();

        //remove student Student in linked list
        /*for (Student student : studentPack)
            {
            if ((student.getFirstName().equals(userFirstName)) && (student.getLastName().equals(userLastName)))
                {
                studentPack.remove(student);
                break;
                }
            }
            model.removeStudent(int i);
        */}
    });

    exitMenuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    //nest button and list panels in combined content panel
    combinedPanel.add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    combinedPanel.add(tablePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    combinedPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    //add combined content panel to frame
    jFrame.add(combinedPanel);
    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
    "***Click a cell to edit data*** \n ***Click a column header to sort***", "How to edit/sort data", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }

public class tableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

public final String[] columnNames = { "First Name", "Last Name", "Major:", "GPA", "UIN", "NetID", "Age", "Gender" };
private MyList data;

public tableModel(MyList data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnNames[column];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public void addStudent(Student student) {
        int row = data.size();
        data.add(student);
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
    }

public void removeStudent(int i) {
        int row = data.size();
        data.remove(i);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(row, row);
    }

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    Student student = data.get(rowIndex);
    if (student == null) {
        return null;
    }
    switch (columnIndex) {
    case 0:
        return student.getFirstName();
    case 1:
        return student.getLastName();
    case 2:
        return student.getMajor();
    case 3:
        return student.getGPA();
    case 4:
        return student.getUIN();
    case 5:
        return student.getNetID();
    case 6:
        return student.getAge();
    case 7:
        return student.getGender();
    default:
        return null;
    }
}
}
}
```

Here's the class for my student object

```
public class Student {
    // Declare attributes here
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String major;
    double gpa;
    String uin;
    String netid;
    int age;
    String gender;

    public Student(String newFirstName, String newLastName, String newMajor, double newGPA, String newUIN, String newNetID, int newAge, String newGender){
        setFirstName(newFirstName);
        setLastName(newLastName);
        setMajor(newMajor);
        setGPA(newGPA);
        setUIN(newUIN);
        setNetID(newNetID);
        setAge(newAge);
        setGender(newGender);
    }

    //Mutators
    public void setFirstName(String newFirstName) {
        firstName = newFirstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String newLastName) {
        lastName = newLastName;
    }

    public void setMajor(String newMajor) {
        major = newMajor;
    }

    public void setGPA(double newGPA) {
        gpa = newGPA;
    }

    public void setUIN(String newUIN) {
        uin = newUIN;
    }

    public void setNetID(String newNetID) {
        netid = newNetID;
    }

    public void setAge(int newAge) {
        age = newAge;
    }

    public void setGender(String newGender) {
        gender = newGender;
    }

    //Accessors
        public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

        public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

        public String getMajor() {
        return major;
    }

        public double getGPA() {
        return gpa;
    }

        public String getUIN() {
        return uin;
    }

        public String getNetID() {
        return netid;
    }

        public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

        public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

Here's the class for my custom list

```
    class MyList {

    private static int counter;
    private Node head;

    // Default constructor
public MyList() {

}

// appends the specified element to the end of this list.
public void add(Student data) {
// Initialize Node only incase of 1st element
if (head == null) {
head = new Node(data);
}

Node temp = new Node(data);
Node current = head;

// Check for NPE before iterate over current
if (current != null) {
// starting at the head node, crawl to the end of the list and then add element after last node
while (current.getNext() != null) {
current = current.getNext();
}
// the last node's "next" reference set to our new node
current.setNext(temp);
}

// increment the number of elements variable
incrementCounter();
}

private static int getCounter() {
return counter;
}

private static void incrementCounter() {
counter++;
}

private void decrementCounter() {
counter--;
}

// inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list
public void add(Student data, int index) {
Node temp = new Node(data);
Node current = head;

// Check for NPE before iterate over current
if (current != null) {
// crawl to the requested index or the last element in the list, whichever comes first
for (int i = 0; i < index && current.getNext() != null; i++) {
current = current.getNext();
}
}

// set the new node's next-node reference to this node's next-node reference
temp.setNext(current.getNext());

// now set this node's next-node reference to the new node
current.setNext(temp);

// increment the number of elements variable
incrementCounter();
}

public Student get(int index)
// returns the element at the specified position in the list.
{
// index must be 1 or higher
if (index <= 0)
return null;
Node current = null;
if (head != null) {
current = head.getNext();
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
if (current.getNext() == null)
return null;
current = current.getNext();
}
return current.getData();
}
return current.getData();
}

// removes the element at the specified position in this list.
public boolean remove(int index) {

// if the index is out of range, exit
if (index < 1 || index > size())
return false;

Node current = head;
if (head != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
if (current.getNext() == null)
return false;

current = current.getNext();
}
current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext());

// decrement the number of elements variable
decrementCounter();
return true;

}
return false;
}

// returns the number of elements in this list.
public int size() {
return getCounter();
}

public String toString() {
String output = "";

if (head != null) {
Node current = head.getNext();
while (current != null) {
output += "[" + current.getData().toString() + "]";
current = current.getNext();
}

}
return output;
}

private class Node {
// reference to the next node in the chain
Node next;

// data carried by the node
Student data;

// Node constructor
public Node(Student dataValue) {
next = null;
data = dataValue;
}

// another Node constructor to specify the node to point to.
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public Node(Student dataValue, Node nextValue) {
next = nextValue;
data = dataValue;
}

public Student getData() {
return data;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public void setData(Student dataValue) {
data = dataValue;
}

public Node getNext() {
return next;
}

public void setNext(Node nextValue) {
next = nextValue;
}

}
}
```

Comment: `private static int counter;` worries me

Comment: You `getValueAt` method has a compilation error because you're method signature wants to return a `Student`, but you're actually trying to return `String`s, maybe change it to `Object` instead; `public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {`

Comment: Your "add" functionality never tells the `TableModel` that a new student has been added to the table model, maybe instead, add a `addStudent` method to the `TableModel` which updates the `MyList` and fires an appropriate modification event, like `fireTableRowsInserted`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, basically, you need to add a `add` method to your `StudentTableModel` which can add the new `Student` to the `MyList` and generate the required update events to tell the table to repaint itself.

Something like...

```
public void addStudent(Student student) {
    int row = data.size();
    data.add(student);
    fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
}
```

Which would be be added to your `StudentTableModel`, something like...

```
public class StudentTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    public final String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Major:", "GPA", "UIN", "NetID", "Age", "Gender"};
    private MyList data;

    public StudentTableModel(MyList data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return columnNames[column];
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        int row = data.size();
        System.out.println(row);
        System.out.println(student);
        data.add(student);
        fireTableRowsInserted(row, row);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Student student = data.get(rowIndex);
        if (student == null) {
            return null;
        }
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return student.getFirstName();
            case 1:
                return student.getLastName();
            case 2:
                return student.getMajor();
            case 3:
                return student.getGPA();
            case 4:
                return student.getUIN();
            case 5:
                return student.getNetID();
            case 6:
                return student.getAge();
            case 7:
                return student.getGender();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would actually need to apply the model to the `JTable`...

```
private StudentTableModel model;
//...
model = new StudentTableModel(new MyList());
JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

and then, instead of...

```
Student studentStudent = new Student(userFirstName, userLastName, userMajor, userGPA, userUIN, userNetID, userAge, userGender);
//store Student in linked list
studentPack.add(studentStudent);
```

you would do something like...

```
Student studentStudent = new Student(userFirstName, userLastName, userMajor, userGPA, userUIN, userNetID, userAge, userGender);
//store Student in linked list
model.add(studentStudent);
```

After spending some time playing around with your code, it became evident that your `MyList` has issues.  My recommendation would be to test and debug your `MyList` first before getting the UI involved, it will be easier

I would also take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

Comment: Two related examples are seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36522182/230513).

Comment: I've update my work above. Hopefully I didn't botch your suggestions too much... It now at least runs but does not actually populate the table with the input data. I read both your suggested readings but nothing is jumping out at me.

Comment: @Coobs I had a runnable example based on your `MyList` and the `StudentTableModel` in the answer that "kind" of work, because, as I stated, your linked list implementation is "broken" and needs to be fixed, which frankly, I just don't have time to do for you.  Fix that first, then come back to the `JTable`