# How to update a jtable, when using a custom TableModel with a list of items read from a file

Tags: java, swing, csv, jtable, tablemodel

i have a problem with my Jtable/TableModel that no matter how much i try i cant seem to fix. im working on an address book program, without a database program since our professor want us to learn everything by hand, so what i have is a .csv file that i use to read/write contacts on. i read the contacts in the file, put them on a list, use that list to form a TableModel around it, and then make a Jtable with said TableModel. my problem comes up, when if i write a new contact on the file, the jtable will not update itself with the new info, unless i close down the program and start it up again. how would i be able to to make the table update itself with the new info?

heres where i first make the jtable and table model, wont post whole method since its nonrelated.

```
List<Contatcs> listContacts = createListContacts(username);
tableModel = new TableModel(listContacts);

//create table, sorter and set single selection model
jTable = new JTable(tableModel);
final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(tableModel);
JTableHeader jtHeader = jTable.getTableHeader();
```

here's where i create my list of contacts

```
public static List<Contatcs> createListContacts(String username) throws FileNotFoundException{

        String file = "CustomersAddressBooks\\" + username + ".csv";
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(file));
        List<Contatcs> retVal = new ArrayList();
        while (fileReader.hasNextLine()){
            String line = fileReader.nextLine();
            line = line.replaceAll("\r||\n","");
            String[] var = line.split(",");
            if(!line.equals("") && !var[0].equals("FirstName") && !var[1].equals("LastName")){

                retVal.add(new Contatcs(var[0],var[1],var[2],var[3],var[4],var[5],var[6],var[7],var[8]));
            }
        }

        fileReader.close();

        return retVal;
    }
```

and this is my TableModel class

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final int COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = 0;
    private static final int COLUMN_LASTNAME = 1;
    private static final int COLUMN_PHONENUMBER = 2;
    private static final int COLUMN_CITY = 3;

    private String[] columnNames = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Phone Number", "City"};
    private List<Contatcs> listContacts;

    public TableModel(List<Contatcs> listContacts){
        this.listContacts = listContacts;
        int indexCount = 1;
        for(Contatcs contact : listContacts){
            contact.setIndex(indexCount++);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return listContacts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Contatcs contacts = listContacts.get(rowIndex);
        Object retVal = null;
        switch(columnIndex){
        case COLUMN_FIRSTNAME: retVal = contacts.getFirstName(); break;
        case COLUMN_LASTNAME: retVal = contacts.getLastName(); break;
        case COLUMN_PHONENUMBER: retVal = contacts.getPhoneNumber(); break;
        case COLUMN_CITY: retVal = contacts.getCity(); break;
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid column index.");
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex){
        return columnNames[columnIndex];
    }
    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex){
        if(listContacts.isEmpty()) return Object.class;
        else return getValueAt(0,columnIndex).getClass();
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle.

Comment: Don't recycle the interface name `TableModel` for a subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little exemple who to do it:

```
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    String[] column_name = new String[]{"Col1","Col2"};
    Vector<String[]> list_value=new Vector<String[]>();

    public TableModel() {
    }

    //add just one line the table
    public void add_row(String[] row_values){
        list_value.add(row_values);
    }

    //change the list 
    public void setList(Vector<String[]>list){
        this.list_value=list;
    }



    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return column_name.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return list_value.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return list_value.get(row)[col];
    }

}
```

and this is the frame :

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private JButton button1;
    private JTextField val1;
    private JTextField val2;
    private JScrollPane scrollpanel;
    private JButton button_replace;
    private JTable table1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame frame=new MainFrame();
        frame.show();
    }

    public MainFrame() {
        super();
        //creating components   
        FlowLayout thisLayout = new FlowLayout();
        getContentPane().setLayout(thisLayout);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        button1 = new JButton();
        getContentPane().add(button1);
        button1.setText("add");
        button1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(81, 23));
        val1 = new JTextField();
        getContentPane().add(val1);
        val1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(51, 23));
        val2 = new JTextField();
        getContentPane().add(val2);
        val2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(53, 23));
        pack();
        setSize(400, 300);
        //add the table now
        scrollpanel = new JScrollPane();        
        scrollpanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(339, 169));
        getContentPane().add(scrollpanel);
        table1 = new JTable();
        scrollpanel.setViewportView(table1);
        table1.setModel(new jtableExemple.TableModel());
        TableModel table_model=(TableModel) table1.getModel();
        table_model.add_row(new String[]{"row1","row1"});
        table_model.add_row(new String[]{"row2","row2"});
        table_model.add_row(new String[]{"row3","row3"});
        button_replace = new JButton();
        getContentPane().add(button_replace);
        button_replace.setText("Replace all list");


        //add action to button 
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            TableModel table_model=(TableModel) table1.getModel();
            table_model.add_row(new String[]{val1.getText(),val2.getText()});
            //this line to the change in the UI 
            table1.setRowHeight(table1.getRowHeight());
            }
        });

        button_replace.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //create a random list
                TableModel table_model=(TableModel) table1.getModel();
                Vector<String[]>new_list=new Vector<String[]>();
                for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
                    new_list.add(new String[]{"new row "+i,"new row "+i});
                table_model.setList(new_list);
                //this line to the change in the UI 
                table1.setRowHeight(table1.getRowHeight());             
            }
        });

}


}
```

Comment: Constructive criticism: If `addRow()` fired a suitable `TableModelEvent`, conveniently supplied by `AbstractTableModel`, you would't need the spurious call to adjust the row height. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: `DefaultTableModel` is a standard example; more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36522182/230513).

Comment: can you edit my answer and show me what to do to remove the setRowHeigh ?!

Comment: I'm happy to guide you; try firing an event in your add row method and see how it works.

Comment: thank you a lot : i added fireTableRowsInserted(list_value.size()-1, list_value.size()-1); and it worked now time to learn about this events

Comment: thanks for the help guys, my problem was that i wasnt updating the array list that the tablemodel was based on, once i did that it all worked out. i have one final problem tho, that i been attempting to fix for a 2 days, in my project i have a log out button that will clear the arraylist so that it can be fill up new contacts for whoever logs in again, the issue i have is that even tho i repopulate the list with new info, the tablemodel doesnt seem to notice that and still thinks theres an empty list, so it display nothings for whoever logs in, after someone else logs out

Comment: never mind guys i had an epiphany moment and figured out that that even tho i was repopulating the array list, it was actually crating a new object and the table model was stuck on the previous list. thanks for all replies and help anyways.